# When is the load of a detachableloadablemodel called in java wicket?

Tags: java, wicket

In my code I have a something like the following:

The wicket form:

```
public class MyForm extends Form<MyFormModel> {
    public MyForm(String id){
        super(id, new CompoundPropertyModel<MyFormModel>(new MyFormModel())

        //add some labels from the CompoundPropertyModel

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSubmit() {

        setResponsePage(new NewPage(getModelObject()));

    }
}
```

The form model:

```
public class MyFormModel extends LoadableDetachableModel<List<NotSerializableObject>> {

    transient List<NotSerializableObject> list;

    //Some labels with getters and setters for CompoundPropertyModel use

    protected List<NotSerializableObject> load() {
        //list = dbstuff.getstuff()
    } 
}
```

When the page is loaded with `MyForm` on it, the `MyFormModel` uses the `load()` function and tries to access the db before the form is submitted. I don't understand why because `getModelObject()` isn't called until the form is submitted and `onSubmit()` is called.

I understand that the CompoundPropertyModel and LoadableDetachableModel should be split to solve this but why does this not work? Why and from where is the load() function called?

Thanks for any help,

Martin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the Form is displayed, each of the FormComponent s ask its Model for the value. The first call to getModelObject() (out of my head, have not done much wicket recently) is chained to the load() in the LoadableDetacheableModel.

Answer (score 1):

It looks there is a component added to MyForm (your code snippet omits that part of code). If any of MyForm component access the model then the getModel().getObject() -> load() is called. Remeber that CompoundPropertyModel use also the getObject() on the inner model.

Comment: I add some Textfields like so: `add(new TextField<String>("compoundPropertyVar"));`. But when I debug, I do not enter the `load()` function when addingthese TextFields. It also enters the function only once while there are multiple TextFields so `getObject()` is not called for each property.

Comment: TextField component invokes getObject() through property model (or CompoundPropertyModel) that invokes load(). That is the reason.

Comment: The invoking is somewhere during the lifecycle of the component and each request.